# Is there a way to suppress chunk name in figure captions when using R markdown?

Tags: r-markdown

Is there a way to set R markdown so that the chunk name does not get included with the figure caption.

Below is an example.  I would like to use "Figure Caption" as the caption instead of "chunkname Figure Caption".  I just want to use chunkname as a reference for navigating through the markdown file when editing.

````
```{r chunkname, fig.cap="Figure Caption"}

knitr::include_graphics("image.png")

```
````

Answer (score 2):

I was using blogdown.  The error was caused by using an underscore in the chunk name.

https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/336

I'm not sure what the proper etiquette on this site is.  Should I remove this post?

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot! I had no idea why the name of the chunk was appearing in the caption of my tables.  To complete your answer, even a dot in the chunk name causes this problem.

Comment: if you removed it, I would not have been helped today! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your other code looks like in the Rmarkdown file, but that is not how Rmarkdown normally works, when I use your Code, I get the outcome you are wanting

[image]